# Android bug with preferences?

Tags: java, android

So I have an app that uses various currency symbols and you can select whichever you like via the standard preference view and I noticed that if a currency uses the same symbol e.g. USD, AUD, SGD ($) it will default to the last item in the list. For instance, from the list below if I choose USD or AUD it will default to SGD when I click again but if I choose say ZAR, MYR, EUR, or GBP it will stick to that one as the value doesn't repeat. Am I doing something wrong here or is this a known issue?

```
    <string-array name="currency">
    <item name="eur">EUR</item>
    <item name="gbp">GBP</item>
    <item name="jpy">JPY</item> 
    <item name="usd">USD</item>
    <item name="zar">ZAR</item> 
    <item name="myr">MYR</item>     
    <item name="cny">CNY</item> 
    <item name="aud">AUD</item> 
    <item name="sgd">SGD</item>                                                                                                                                                                         
</string-array>

<string-array name="currencyValues">
    <item name="eur">€</item>
    <item name="gbp">£</item>
    <item name="jpy">¥</item>
    <item name="usd">$</item>
    <item name="zar">R</item>   
    <item name="myr">MR</item>  
    <item name="cny">¥</item>   
    <item name="aud">$</item>   
    <item name="sgd">$</item>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</string-array>
```

Comment: It's just a preference(settings) view so basically my relevant code looks as:                                    android:entries="@array/currency"
android:entryValues="@array/currencyValues"

Comment: If I didn't have three values with the $ symbol it would work fine and the values would stick but as of now it defaults to the last entry that uses the symbol (SGD). And as you can see the name for each entry is different so why does it default to SGD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a bug because it's not said what should happen with duplicate values. The reason I'm saying this is behind the curtain there's no way of knowing which of the entries was chosen as only the actual value ($ in the special case) is saved.

One way to get around it is to have the currency name (or an integer for each currency) in the values and have a secondary function to parse it to the currency symbol. Another quicker hack is to save both the currency name and symbol, like `AUD$` and only show the last character when you want to use it.

However, my suggestion is to use the currency name as well to avoid confusion between the different currencies. Wikipedia for instance says USD, SGD and AUD sometimes is abbreviated with US$, S$ and A$, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of just doing something like that to get around the issue.